# webrtc_android native api not find the AppRTCMobile example

Tags: android, git, webrtc

I'm on ubuntu 16.04 and try to install on my lollipop 5.1 tablet, native api webrtc example (AppRtcMobile example).

I successfully installed chromium on my lollipop device. Now after removing the folders used to install chromium on the lollipop device from the ubuntu pc I'm trying to compile an example project about webrtc using the grandle system or adb at the command line. But the compilation always stops at the same point.

Unfortunately, I'm new to git, ninja, fetch and gn, so I do not understand where the error is.

I follow the procedure that I describe below (as I understand that the commands work) and create 3 different installation directories so as to install even on devices other than "arm".

```txt
git clone https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/tools/depot_tools.git

export PATH=$PATH:/my-path/to/depot_tools

mkdir ~/webrTEST && cd ~/webrtcTEST

fetch --nohooks webrtc_android

gclient sync

./build/install-build-deps.sh

gn gen out/DebugArm --args='target_os="android" target_cpu="arm"'

gn gen out/DebugArm64 --args='target_os="android" target_cpu="arm64"'

gn gen out/DebugX64 --args='target_os="android" target_cpu="x64"'


ninja -C out/DebugArm

ninja -C out/DebugArm64

ninja -C out/DebugX64

. build/android/envsetup.sh

ninja -C out/DebugX64 AppRTCMobile
```

I try to study more than one "tutorial" and [the offial guide too](https://webrtc.org/native-code/android/), but ninja retur everytime the same result:

```txt
myuser@mymachine:~~/webrtcTEST/src$ ninja -C out/DebugX64 AppRTCMobile
ninja: Entering directory `out/DebugX64'
ninja: no work to do.
```

Anyone can suggest my where is/sre my error?

regards
bkt

UPDATE:

using ls command not find AppRTCMobile but other app example or other ...

the command:

```
ninja -C out/DebugX64 :xxxx/xxxx/xxxx
```

work great ... so at these point the question change into:

where is the old AppRTCMobile example located or which is the new name of the example that allows me to android lollipop to use the server google appr.tc ??

Any how if in my manner of install the webrtc-android git there are some error please help my to find it.

regards
bkt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not understand the reason, but by deleting everything and re executing the procedure written in the application I got the desired result and I compiled AppRTCMobile.